# Installation of data-lineage package in python throwing an error

Tags: python, python-3.x, installation, pip, pyinstaller

I am trying to follow the instructions mentioned at this link - https://docs.tokern.io/data-lineage/installation/#setup-the-postgres-database

I created a local postgres DB and created an admin user. But when I try to install the data-lineage package using
`pip install data-lineage`, I get the following error:

```
Collecting mysqlclient<3,>=1.3.6 (from amundsen-databuilder[athena,bigquery,glue,rds,snowflake]<7,>=6->dbcat<0.8.0,>=0.7.1->data-lineage)
  Using cached mysqlclient-2.2.0.tar.gz (89 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [24 lines of output]
      /bin/sh: pkg-config: command not found
      /bin/sh: pkg-config: command not found
      Trying pkg-config --exists mysqlclient
      Command 'pkg-config --exists mysqlclient' returned non-zero exit status 127.
      Trying pkg-config --exists mariadb
      Command 'pkg-config --exists mariadb' returned non-zero exit status 127.
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/Users/abc/.env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "/Users/abc/.env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
        File "/Users/abc/.env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return hook(config_settings)
        File "/private/var/folders/vm/tn3bdwhx2zd788hmwxd_y33m0000gp/T/pip-build-env-qhjtjvce/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 341, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=['wheel'])
        File "/private/var/folders/vm/tn3bdwhx2zd788hmwxd_y33m0000gp/T/pip-build-env-qhjtjvce/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 323, in _get_build_requires
          self.run_setup()
        File "/private/var/folders/vm/tn3bdwhx2zd788hmwxd_y33m0000gp/T/pip-build-env-qhjtjvce/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 338, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 154, in <module>
        File "<string>", line 48, in get_config_posix
        File "<string>", line 27, in find_package_name
      Exception: Can not find valid pkg-config name.
      Specify MYSQLCLIENT_CFLAGS and MYSQLCLIENT_LDFLAGS env vars manually
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.
```

I tried a lot of different things as follows:

- upgraded python version
- upgraded pip version
- tried to install wheel using `pip3 install wheel`
- tried to install using `pip3 install -e data-lineage`

Nothing seems to help my cause. Anyone faced the same issue and were able to resolve it?

Comment: Maybe you need to install `pkg-config` package on your system for building the wheel.

Comment: Try running `sudo apt-get install python3-dev default-libmysqlclient-dev build-essential`